# Switching the displayed surface in PyGame allows the user to scroll off the borders of the surface

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, scroll, pygame

I am creating a randomly generated map in with PyGame. However, I've run into an issue, where, if the user scrolls away from the top-left corner of the map and changes the PyGame surface that's displayed, an issue happens.

The problem is, PyGame still starts them on the upper-left of the surface, and will then allow them to scroll off the edges of the surface because the list that keeps track of that, `camera_pos`, now has incorrect values.

All of the surfaces are the same dimensions and I want to make it so the user is in the same position when they change the displayed surface. However, I'm not sure how to set the position of the user's view when pygame switches surfaces.

*How can I switch the position of the user's view back to what it used to be when the surface is switched?*

I have made a MCV Example below I hope will help. Instead of displaying maps, it just draws a border around a solid color. I apologize for how long it is. I'm not sure how to make it much shorter.

In this example, scrolling is done with the arrow keys. You can press r, g, or b on the keyboard to display the different colored surfaces.

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import sys

def scroll_y(display_surface, offset):
    """
    Handles vertical scrolling.

    :param display_surface: A pyGame surface object.
    :param offset: The speed of the scroll
    """

    width, height = display_surface.get_size()

    map_copy = display_surface.copy()

    display_surface.blit(map_copy, (0, offset))

    # handle scrolling down
    if offset < 0:
        display_surface.blit(map_copy,
                             (0, height + offset),
                             (0, 0, width, -offset))

    # handle scrolling up
    else:
        display_surface.blit(map_copy,
                             (0, 0),
                             (0, height - offset, width, offset))


def scroll_x(display_surface, offset):
    """
    Handles horizontal scrolling.

    :param display_surface: A pyGame surface object.
    :param offset: The speed of the scroll
    """

    width, height = display_surface.get_size()

    map_copy = display_surface.copy()

    display_surface.blit(map_copy, (offset, 0))

    # handle scrolling right
    if offset < 0:
        display_surface.blit(map_copy,
                             (width + offset, 0),
                             (0, 0, -offset, height))

    # handle scrolling left
    else:
        display_surface.blit(map_copy,
                             (0, 0),
                             (width - offset, 0, offset, height))


def main():
    """
    This function displays the three surfaces.

    Press r to show the red surface (which is displayed by default).
    Press g to show the green surface.
    Press b to show the blue surface.
    """
    pygame.init()

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900))

    red_surface = pygame.Surface([3200, 1800]).convert(window)
    green_surface = pygame.Surface([3200, 1800]).convert(window)
    blue_surface = pygame.Surface([3200, 1800]).convert(window)

    red_surface.fill((255, 145, 145))
    green_surface.fill((145, 255, 145))
    blue_surface.fill((145, 145, 255))

    # draw thick black lines on surface borders
    pygame.draw.rect(red_surface, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 3200, 1800), 40)
    pygame.draw.rect(green_surface, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 3200, 1800), 40)
    pygame.draw.rect(blue_surface, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 3200, 1800), 40)

    display_surface = red_surface.copy()

    camera_pos = np.array([0, 0])

    while True:  # <-- the pyGame loop

        event = pygame.event.poll()

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # handle closing the window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

        window.blit(display_surface, (0, 0))

        # handle switching display modes
        if pressed[pygame.K_g]:
            display_surface = green_surface
        elif pressed[pygame.K_b]:
            display_surface = blue_surface
        elif pressed[pygame.K_r]:
            display_surface = red_surface

        # handle scrolling, make sure you can't scroll past the borders
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP] and camera_pos[1] > 0:
            scroll_y(display_surface, 5)
            camera_pos[1] -= 5

        elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and camera_pos[1] < (1800 / 2):
            scroll_y(display_surface, -5)
            camera_pos[1] += 5

        elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and camera_pos[0] > 0:
            scroll_x(display_surface, 5)
            camera_pos[0] -= 5

        elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and camera_pos[0] < (3200 / 2):
            scroll_x(display_surface, -5)
            camera_pos[0] += 5

        # updates what the window displays
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # runs the pyGame loop
    main()
```

Comment: It's a little hard to see the effects of scrolling since there's nothing on the surfaces. Regardless, to do what you want, it seems like you need save the current x and y offset values and use then when switching surfaces so the replacement is in the same position as the previous surface was before the switch.

Comment: @martineau That's what I'm having problems with. I don't know how to do that. I got the scroll functions here from another question, and I'm not entirely sure how they do what they do.

Comment: LuminousNutria: Can't work on it right now. Will take a look at it in a while and see if I can come-up with something (assumes someone else hasn't already answered your question by then).

Comment: @martineau thank you, I can wait :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think is a fairly elegant solution that doesn't require the two scrolling functions, `scroll_x()` and `scroll_y()` you have. Because it was so fast not using them, the main loop was detecting the same scrolling key as being pressed multiple times — necessitating the addition of a `pygame.time.Clock` to slow the frame-rate down to something reasonable.

Instead of scrolling the display surfaces themselves via those scrolling functions, as your code was doing, this version just updates the current "camera" position, then blits the corresponding region of the current `display_surface` to the window whenever it's modified. The camera's position is constrained by making sure its x and y components stay within some boundary limit constants — `MINX`,`MINY` and `MAXX`,`MAXY` — which get computed based the values of some other previously defined constants.

The use of symbolic constants rather than hardcoding literal values multiple places in the code is considered a very good programming practice because it makes changing them easier, since doing so only requires a source code change to be done one place.

```
import pygame
import sys


def main():
    """
    This function displays the three surfaces.

    Press r to show the red surface (which is displayed by default).
    Press g to show the green surface.
    Press b to show the blue surface.
    """
    FPS = 60  # Frames per second
    SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT = 3200, 1800
    WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT = 1600, 900
    DX, DY = 5, 5  # Scroll amounts.
    MINX, MAXX = DX, SURF_WIDTH - WIN_WIDTH + DX - 1
    MINY, MAXY = DY, SURF_HEIGHT - WIN_HEIGHT + DY - 1

    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    fonts = pygame.font.get_fonts()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    red_surface = pygame.Surface([SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT]).convert(window)
    green_surface = pygame.Surface([SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT]).convert(window)
    blue_surface = pygame.Surface([SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT]).convert(window)

    red_surface.fill((255, 145, 145))
    green_surface.fill((145, 255, 145))
    blue_surface.fill((145, 145, 255))

    # Draw thick black lines on surface borders
    pygame.draw.rect(red_surface, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT), 40)
    pygame.draw.rect(green_surface, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT), 40)
    pygame.draw.rect(blue_surface, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, SURF_WIDTH, SURF_HEIGHT), 40)

    # Draw label on each of the surfaces for testing. (ADDED)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)

    rtext = font.render('red surface', True, (255, 0, 0))
    textpos = rtext.get_rect(centerx=300, centery=200)  # Reused.
    red_surface.blit(rtext, textpos)

    rtext = font.render('green surface', True, (0, 192, 0))
    green_surface.blit(rtext, textpos)

    rtext = font.render('blue surface', True, (0, 0, 255))
    blue_surface.blit(rtext, textpos)

    display_surface = red_surface
    camera_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    update_surface = True

    while True:  # Game loop

        if update_surface:
            window.blit(display_surface, (0, 0), (camera_pos[0], camera_pos[1],
                                                  WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
            update_surface = False

        event = pygame.event.poll()
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # Close window?
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            break

        # Switch display surface?
        if pressed[pygame.K_g]:
            display_surface = green_surface
            update_surface = True
        elif pressed[pygame.K_b]:
            display_surface = blue_surface
            update_surface = True
        elif pressed[pygame.K_r]:
            display_surface = red_surface
            update_surface = True

        # Constrain scrolling to within borders
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and camera_pos[0] >= MINX:
            camera_pos[0] -= DX
            update_surface = True
        elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and camera_pos[0] <= MAXX:
            camera_pos[0] += DX
            update_surface = True
        elif pressed[pygame.K_UP] and camera_pos[1] >= MINY:
            camera_pos[1] -= DY
            update_surface = True
        elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and camera_pos[1] <= MAXY:
            camera_pos[1] += DY
            update_surface = True

        # updates what the window displays
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()  # runs the pyGame loop
```

Comment: LuminousNutria: Want to point out that since the scrolling functions have been eliminate, you could now easily allow diagonal moves to be also made, — doing so would only require checking for the keypresses and updating `camera_pos` value accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip! I will definitely allow diagonal scrolling.

Comment: LuminousNutria: Good to hear. Caveat: I may have over-stated how simple it would be to implement diagonal moves, because doing so will require checking _both_ current x and y `camera_pos` values to ensure the new values will be within bounds — instead of just one or the other as done currently.